# Equivalence of two definitions of Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Assuming the following definition of Riemann integrability I want to prove that if $f$ is Riemann integrable then for any given $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a partition $P$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$.

$Def$: A function $f$ is Riemann Integrable if there exist a finite no. $I$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a partition $P$ such that for all $T$ $|R(f,P,T) - I| < \epsilon$. $R(f,P,T)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_i)(x_i - x_{i-1})$ is Riemann sum, where $t_i \in [x_{i-1} - x_i]$ $T=\{t_0,t_1,\dots\}$ is such a partition inside $P$.

I guess I need to use triangle inequality, but stuck in finishing the proof.

Comment: what is $T$ there?

Comment: What is R ? Please state the variables clearly.

Comment: problem solved.